# architecture for IOT

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-app-engine, raspberry-pi, iot

I'm trying to create a product where customers have remote Raspberry Pi computers. These computers should be able to submit captured images and metadata to cloud file storage once a day (e.g., Google Cloud Storage)

How would you organize such system in terms of security, key storage, protocols, etc?

I reviewed Google Cloud IOT, but this solution seems to be an overkill. maybe I'm wrong. Also, seems like passing images via such solution is too expensive.
but I like the part of device management and software upgrades.
Is it better to use Google Cloud IOT or Amazon IOT or try to develop a more simple solution on my own?

Answer (score 3):

Cloud IoT (Google's or Amazon's) is going to be overkill for what you're talking about.

Google Cloud Storage has [APIs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) (pick your language, I personally like Node.js, but there's APIs for C#, GO, Java, Node.js, PHP, Python and Ruby). Since you're using Raspberry Pi, they can run these APIs directly. Setup a cron job to run your script to push whatever you want into a storage bucket.

You'll need to setup an account on Google Cloud Platform to use the APIs. There's very good quickstart guides on this [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstarts).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go ahead and use Google Cloud IoT, you can try the Cloud IoT Core API, there is a good tutorial for it [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/quickstart). As indicated in the quickstart, I would recommend using Node.js for this API.

After that, you can integrate this API with Cloud Storage or another storage product that you see fit (Datastore, BigTable, etc.). As it was said before, you can setup a cron job for the storage operations.